# NoMethodError: undefined method `create_reset_digest' for #<User:0x007fba32e0af58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, railstutorial.org

I got these 5 errors upon doing a bundle rake exec test. I have no idea how to resolve it. I've googled and googled with no end in site (see what I did there). Now I turn to you for help!

If you accept, these are the errors:

```
  1) Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_reset_digest' for #<User:0x007fba32e0af58>
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'


  2) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `current_user?' for #<#<Class:0x007fba2cdf19a0>:0x007fba28cd32c0>
    app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_microposts__micropost_html_erb___3978616761423832463_70218762096200'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2170813965465965459_70218768032700'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'


  3) Error:
UsersProfileTest#test_profile_display:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `current_user?' for #<#<Class:0x007fba2cdf19a0>:0x007fba2f8c51e0>
    app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_microposts__micropost_html_erb___3978616761423832463_70218762096200'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2170813965465965459_70218768032700'
    test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'


  4) Error:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `current_user?' for #<#<Class:0x007fba2cdf19a0>:0x007fba28ed08e8>
    app/views/users/_user.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users__user_html_erb__3013593760514997339_70218798383040'
    app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___1851646122892737362_70218763684120'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'


  5) Error:
MicropostsInterfaceTest#test_micropost_interface:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `current_user?' for #<#<Class:0x007fba312ac360>:0x007fba2ff66120>
    app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_microposts__micropost_html_erb___3978616761423832463_70218762096200'
    app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___1999510692289199836_70218832039180'
    app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__315324690869897794_70218832802580'
    test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:MicropostsInterfaceTest>'
```

BACKSTORY: I ignored these errors messages as I went through a few of the chapters. I'm not sure if it popped up between 9, 10, or 11. I am new to programming so I don't know if this is enough information for you to be able to help me. The deeper I get into programming material the more it all seems confusing. SOS

Comment: Rule #1: Don't ignore error messages. They are errors, not warnings. Rule #2: Don't ignore warnings lest they become errors.

Comment: I've learned my lesson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are following the https://www.railstutorial.org
You have a recurring `undefined method 'current_user'` error in [2, 3, 4, 5]

Did you defined the `current_user` helper method [as it should be done in your `session_helper.rb`](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-current_user) ?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get my errors down to 1. I've tried the past 2 hours to figure this one out, but I'm hoping you'll have better luck than me. Thanks again!   1) Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at=' for #<User:0x007fdd9c3af0a8>
    app/models/user.rb:63:in `create_reset_digest'
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'